# Why is "flex"-Property not working any more in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flexbox

With React-Native 0.26 i could style a screen with a header and a large panel in proportion 1:10 when passing "`flex:1`" to the header and "`flex:9`" to the other view.

However, with newest React-Native > 0.40 this is not working any more.

**What is wrong with my styles?**

### This is the render function:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={s.container}>
        <View style={s.progressBar}>
          <Progress.Bar progress={this.state.progress} width={200} />
        </View>
        <ListView
          style={s.listView}
          enableEmptySections={true}
          keyboardShouldPersistTaps="always"
          keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(contact) => this._renderContact(contact)}
        />
      </View>

    )
  }
```

### These are the styles:

```
const s = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },

  progressBar: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: 'lightgray',
    height: 20,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  },

  listView: {
    flex: 10,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
  }

});
```

## This happens now:

Wether `flex: 1` is working nor the `height`-property. It does not matter if these properties are passed or not. It always divides the screen into 2 subviews with the same height:

[image]

What i want to achieve is to give the gray area a height of either 20 pixel or 10 percent of the screen.

Comment: Which one do you want? 10 percent or 20 pixels? and you can remove `alignSelf` from `progressBar`, it's not what you need there.

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap ListView tag inside a View and put the style on the View instead:

```html
<View style{{flex: 1}}>
    <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        <Text>This is my header</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={{flex: 10}}>
        <ListView
          dataSource={YOUR_SOURCE}
          renderRow={YOUR_RENDER_CALLBACK}
        />
    </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

For the scrollview try passing styles using the "contentContainerStyle" prop